# Simulate Keypress With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

Using jQuery, how can I simulate (trigger?) a KeyPress when a link is clicked?  For example, when a user clicks the following link:

```
<a id="clickforspace" href="#">Click Here</a>
```

Then, by clicking the link, it would be as if they pressed the "spacebar" on their keyboard.

Something like this, I'm assuming:

```
$("#clickforspace").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    //... Some type of code here to initiate "spacebar" //
                                      });
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events) might answer your question.

Comment: I am curious - when trying to replace `click` with spacebar, did you actually want the browser to scroll down on the page? Pressing spacebar on a link usually has the same effect as pressing the page down key.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The keypress event from jQuery is meant to do this sort of work. You can trigger the event by passing a string "keypress" to .trigger(). However to be more specific you can actually pass a jQuery.Event object (specify the type as "keypress") as well and provide any properties you want such as the keycode being the spacebar.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger#eventdata

Read the above documentation for more details.

Comment: Sure, read the documentation, but the poster probably already knew that. The jQuery events documentation is a bit opaque. Andrew Culver gave a direct answer, plus a reference for more information.

Answer (score 143):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.ctrlKey = false;
press.which = 40;
$("whatever").trigger(press);
```

From [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/simulating-keypress-events).

Comment: This will not produce any actual text if used with input control for example.

Comment: @AlexBurtsev - You're right, that is because this only triggers the event handler as if the specificed key was pressed, but not actually presses that key like happens when a key is pressed on the keyboard (probably due to security reasons)

Comment: Is there a reason you intermingle '$' and 'jQuery'?

Comment: What you wrote didn't work for me in jQuery 2.2.3 on Chrome. :(  But this did: `$("whatever").trigger($.Event("keydown", {keyCode: 40}))`

Comment: Building on  Jonathan Benn's method, you can also use the same technique to send the key instead of sending a keycode (since keycodes are marked as deprecated). For instance: $("whatever").trigger($.Event("keyup", {key: "Enter"})) — and optionally, as shown, with different keyboard events.

Comment: @AlanM. I tried many options but only yours worked: $("whatever").trigger($.Event("keyup", {key: "Enter"})). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 43):

Another option:

```
$(el).trigger({type: 'keypress', which: 13, keyCode: 13});
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: I'm not sure what the `which` is for. Only the `keyCode` works for me in SAPUI5 (jQuery 2.2.3 on Chrome)

Answer (score 13):

You could try this SendKeys jQuery plugin:

http://bililite.com/blog/2011/01/23/improved-sendkeys/

> `$(element).sendkeys(string)` inserts string at the insertion point in
>   an input, textarea or other element with contenteditable=true. If the
>   insertion point is not currently in the element, it remembers where
>   the insertion point was when sendkeys was last called (if the
>   insertion point was never in the element, it appends to the end).

Comment: You don't need jQuery to use this, you can use the same functionality by just getting the `bililiteRange` library: https://github.com/dwachss/bililiteRange (in fact, the jQuery plugin is just a thin wrapper around this incredible library that stands on its own).

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
var event = jQuery.Event('keypress');
event.which = 13; 
event.keyCode = 13; //keycode to trigger this for simulating enter
jQuery(this).trigger(event);
```

Comment: [var event = jQuery.Event('keypress');
    event.which = 13; 
    event.keyCode = 13; 
    jQuery(this).trigger(event);] try this

Comment: I needed to click Enter in a dialog, so with the snippet here, I replaced *this* with *#myEl* .. thanks