# Simulate keyboard click via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to simulate keyboard click for Ctrl+Esc via jQuery but it is NOT working.

```
var e=jQuery.Event("keydown",{keyCode:17} && jQuery.Event("keypress",{keyCode:107}));
jQuery("body").trigger(e);
```

Any idea?

Comment: are you sure about the syntax? I don't understand the meaning of {keyCode:17} && jQuery.Event(...)

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10125618/3132718

Comment: By the way, you know that ESC has keyCode 27? ;)

Comment: What is your expecting result? Open windows start menu?

Comment: @A. Wolff No I don't want CTRL + SHIFT + ESC

Comment: @user3535039 Im' talking about CTRL + ESC. So what is your expected result? Have you got any handler on page to handle it or what?

Comment: Just to get the idea how it works I just picked randomly CTRL + ESC

Comment: @user3535039 so then go for user3132718's answer even maybe not what you were expecting

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.ctrlKey = true;
press.which = 27;
$(document).trigger(press);
```

To check which is the keycode of the button: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

I got the main idea from this answer: [Simulate Keypress With jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468384/simulate-keypress-with-jquery/10125618#10125618)

What **you** have done:

```
var e =
   jQuery.Event(
      "keydown", {keyCode:17}
      &&
      jQuery.Event(
         "keypress",{keyCode:107}
      )
   );
jQuery("body").trigger(e);
```

As you can see, this is a wrong syntax.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did before post my code but it's not working ?

Comment: @user3535039 It works as expected, so what are you expecting? That was the purpose of my previous comments. FYI, you cannot trigger any native OS behaviour using javascript, fortunately for security purpose. See expected behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/6t8wG/

Comment: OK, So let's try backspace for prev page respose still not working ... get this : var event = jQuery.Event('keypress');
event.which = 8; 
event.keyCode = 8;
jQuery(this).trigger(event);

Comment: @user3535039 Still for security purpose... Even you could play with history API

Comment: @user3535039 you can get the previous visited page so: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3528324/3132718

Comment: It's just a backspace and still not working. js can help here or it's useless to try because of "security purpose" ?

Comment: I used backspace for example no need to go for prev page

Comment: So what do you want to do?

Comment: @user3132718 if you can't help or can't touch it just don't say anything... Just LEARN the method how it works !! you can do many things with this script it does NOT matter what is the key combination for now !!!

Comment: @user3535039 You should LEARN how to ask a question... Maybe you are looking instead for dispatchEvent, but who knows... (and who cares!)