# How can I use JavaScript / jQuery to trigger tab (9) keypress when the spacebar (32) is clicked?

Tags: jquery, events, keypress, eventtrigger, tabindex

jQuery newbie here trying to figure out all the tricks of the keypress/trigger functions...

Essentially, I am trying to make the spacebar act as the tab key does, focusing on the next element with a specified tabindex in HTML.

Here's some sample HTML I might be using:

```
<div id="item_1" class="clickable" tabindex="1"></div>
<div id="item_2" class="clickable" tabindex="2"></div>
<div id="item_3" class="clickable" tabindex="3"></div>
```

Here's the jQuery I am trying to use now with no luck:

```
$('.clickable').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        e.which = 9;
        $(this).trigger(e);
    }
});
```

I did see this post already: [Simulate Keypress With jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468384/simulate-keypress-with-jquery) but didn't find it too helpful, maybe I am overlooking the basic concepts though. It seems like the solution there wasn't explicitly linking the actions of two different keys.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.clickable').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        $(this).next().focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, that sort of works. It'll now let me use the space bar to tab around the screen once and then stops unless I continue with the tab key. I also have to already be 'focused' on an element with a tabindex for this to do anything (meaning I can't just open the webpage and start space-barring away). This is because HTML tabindexes automatically loop back around when they reach the last one, including a stop in the url address bar. That's why I was hoping to trigger an actual tab keypress instead of just shifting focus. Any thoughts?

Comment: I thought you only wanted it for the `.clickable` classes. If you want it on the whole page, target `$(document)` instead

Comment: So when I tried the $(document).keydown... the spacebar no longer does anything, even when I'm already on a .clickable element

Comment: Hmmm... try some `if` conditionals on `$('[tabindex]').is(':focus')`