# How to do press key event when user will enter into that div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to press arrow down key automatically when user presses enter on my contenteditable div and here is my code i have tried

```
$('body').on('keypress', '.chat_txt', function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).append('\n'); 
            $(this).trigger({ type: 'keypress', which: 40});
        }
});
```

But unfortunately this code is fruitless.
JsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/2q9x4xzm/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate Keypress With jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468384/simulate-keypress-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the following

```
var e = $.Event('keypress');
        e.which = 40;
        $('.chat_txt').trigger(e);
```

Complete code

```
    $('body').on('keypress', '.chat_txt', function(e) {
console.log(e.keyCode);
       if (e.keyCode === 13) {

            var evt = $.Event('keypress');
            evt.keyCode = 40;
            console.log(evt);
            $('.chat_txt').trigger(evt);
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
});

})
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2q9x4xzm/2/)

Comment: weird.... this code actually works... [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/anv8yhou/3/)

Comment: @four . I have created a fiddle also to demonstrate the solution. and had a little fix i.e triggering an event on cht_txt rather than body  `$('.chat_txt').trigger(evt); `

Comment: why do you want to do that

Comment: Because contenteditable div ads <br> tags when you click enter

Comment: It will still work, if you add e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() after triggering the event.