# How to press a key programmatically using jQuery or java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to press a key programatically using jQuery or javascript

i have tried the following

```
    var event = jQuery.Event('keypress');
    event.which = 144;
    event.keyCode = 144;
    jQuery(this).trigger(event);
```

Comment: Please include your full jquery code, what does `this` refer to in your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468384/simulate-keypress-with-jquery

Comment: i just added these lines with in a function, that's it.

Comment: @vetriselvan why haven't you added the full function then?

Comment: Which key you want to press? where? on which element? Share the relevant stuff.

Comment: @vetriselvan Show whole function, and context where it called

Comment: i just want to press f11 key while page load.

Comment: You can try using this one: http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/fullscreen/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.trigger();
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

you can use like this

```
var event = jQuery.Event( "submit" );
$( "form:first" ).trigger( event );
if ( event.isDefaultPrevented() ) {
   // Perform an action...
}
```