# Send keys using javascript on Overleaf

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to send keys (just as if you are typing on the keyboard) on overleaf using javascript and jquery. I can see there is a .ace_cursor object but it does not seem to work when I try to do this:

```
$('.ace_cursor').html('test')
```

Am I using the wrong object to dispatch keys or the wrong approach to do so?

I have also attempted jquery's trigger for all elements in the page. E.g.,

```
$('.ace_content').click(() => {
var e = jQuery.Event( 'keypress', { which: 65} );
$('*').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).trigger(e);
    console.log($(this));
});
})
```

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468384/simulate-keypress-with-jquery

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work. Jquery requires an object to send keys too. I just cannot figure out what is the element that the keys are sent to in overleaf.

Comment: You're saying it doesn't work, but what code did you try that didn't work?

Comment: I added jquery code as an example that does not work. I have triggered keys in every element in the page but nothing. Yet, there must be a way that those divs receive the keys.

Comment: you want to listen to key press on specific element? can u tell me where did you get overleaf from?

Comment: @Michael do you still wait this answer?

Comment: I should have posted that  with the ace-editor you can just connect to it and edit. So no need for an answer on this. Thank you for asking.